# Unpack list and yield its members

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm a Python newbie. My code looks like this:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(100):
        ### code...
        for j in get_list(i): yield j
```

Is there a way to unpack the list returned by `get_list()` and `yield` it directly without looping again using `for j in get_array(i)`? Is there a performance penalty for using another loop?

Or am I doing it right?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: What performance reasons are you thinking about? There would be exactly the same number of yields made either way.

Comment: if the function get_list is actually returning a list, and you want the list in its entirity, you could just yield the whole list, and should you want to aggregate all of the lists returned you can use list.extend(returned_list) to build it together into a single list

Comment: @DanielRoseman Nothing exactly. I'm a noob and I thought that I'm not doing it right and there is a faster, better, more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Maybe something like `itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(gen_list, range(100)))` (`imap` on Python 2).

Answer (score 4):

python3 has `yield from`, so you can `yield from get_list(i)`.

python2 does not have this, so `for ...: yield` loops are sometimes necessary.